# SQL Error [42581]: UCAExc:::5.0.1 unexpected token : INTO required: FROM : line: 2

Tags: sql, ms-access

when I'm trying creating new table in access db via dbeaver using the following code

```
SELECT *
INTO new_tab
FROM tab
WHERE col_name = smth
```

I obtain error

> "SQL Error [42581]: UCAExc:::5.0.1 unexpected token : INTO required: FROM : line: "

What can be the reason of this problem?

I've updated hsqldb.jar to version hsqldb-2.7.1
Please direct me to way where to dig the neccessary information to resolve this bug

Comment: access has no where clause wuth thus construct https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/select-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: The lacking possible where clause is just poor documentation on Microsoft's part. The actual issue is that UCanAccess uses its own SQL engine with its own SQL dialect, not the one provided by Microsoft. While it is modelled after Access SQL and ANSI SQL, some features are not present. Afaik, one of those features is `SELECT .. INTO` queries. It also supports some features Access doesn't, e.g. the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` keywords.

Comment: My search indicates dbeaver can execute SELECT INTO. Since `smth` is literal text, possible need text delimiters: `'smth'`. Or should that be `'smith'`?

Comment: I have tested my SQL query directly in MS Access. It performs successfully. That mean Erik A was absoulutely right and main problem is in UCanAccess engine

Comment: Okay, guess will have to do 2-step process. CREATE TABLE then insert records. If can't use INSERT SELECT Then guess have to open recordset and loop records.

Comment: I am not familiar with dbeaver nor UCANAccess. I definitely found a discussion showing dbeaver building SELECT INTO sql but it was to MySQL.